# how to export @query jpa result into .dat file/

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, apache-poi

I'm using PostgreSQL database,and i have a select query result.I want this query result to save in .dat file.How can i achieve this?

```
@Repository
public interface EmpHeaderRepository extends JpaRepository<EmpHeaderDetails, Long> {

    @Query("select e.header_info from EmpHeaderDetails e" )
    public List<EmpHeaderDetails> findByHeader_info(String header_info);

}
```

This is the query in my repository.

Query result should be saved in the .dat file.How should i do this?

Comment: You can query all your results and just drop them into a regular file name `something.dat`, to write in a file please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-write-to-it-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a file and write to it in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-write-to-it-in-java)

Comment: I'm sorry,but I'm not getting how will i insert queries to writer @ngueno

Comment: Check Ahmet answer, you will fetch your `EmpHeaderDetails`, will iterate over them and save into a regular file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using standard File IO in Java. Just iterate through your result set and save the contents to a file. Sample code is as follows:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("result.dat"));

for(EmpHeaderDetails ehd : ehdList) {
  writer.write(ehd.toString());
}

writer.close();
```

Comment: i'm getting error with ehdList as this variable doesn't contain anything @ngueno What should i do?

Comment: You should first use the repository `findByHeader_info` method and get the result `List<EmpHeaderDetails>` and then assign this result to `ehdList`. Then you can iterate over the collection.

Comment: If the answers worked for you please accept it as answer